# Want to label vertices of a graph and manually move them around

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I would like to plot a graph in such a way that

1. The vertices are labeled using labels that I've given them, rather than just their number,
2. I can manually move the vertices around.

In the code below, `A` is my 4 x 4 adjacency matrix, and `People` specifies the labels that I'd like for the 4 vertices.  `AG` gives me a graph that accomplishes (1) but not (2).  `GP` gives me a graph that satisfies (2) but not (1) -- it only labels the vertices by their number.  How can I accomplish both (1) and (2) simultaneously?  `GraphPLot` does not seem to allow for `VertexLabels` as an option, so I'm at a loss here.

```
A = {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}
People = {Bob, Eric, Lucy, Liz}
AG = AdjacencyGraph[A, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> People[[i]], {i, 1, Length[People]}]]
GP = GraphPlot[AG, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aA = {{0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}};
people = {Bob, Eric, Lucy, Liz};

aG1 = AdjacencyGraph[people, aA, ImageSize -> 300, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20];
aG2 = AdjacencyGraph[aA, ImageSize -> 300, 
   VertexLabels -> Table[i -> people[[i]], {i, 1, Length[people]}], 
   ImagePadding -> 20];
gP = GraphPlot[Rule @@@ EdgeList[aG1], ImageSize -> 300,  VertexLabeling -> True];
Row[{aG1, aG2, gP}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]